# How does TFS store binary files

Tags: architecture, tfs, storage

Quick and simple question I did not find an answer for:

How does TFS store binary files? I know that for text files it stores the complete content of the latest version and diffs to its predecessors. Does the same apply for binary files?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Each time, new complete copy of a binary file is stored.

**Update.** Actually seems like I was partially wrong about this :-). [TFS does stores deltas](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/tfsversioncontrol/thread/fe8d0805-f33b-4415-9add-3a1a277980ae) for binary files, but only if they are smaller then `deltaMaxFileSize` configuration value [stored in web.config file](http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2007/07/maximum-size-of-file-under-source.html) which have default value of 16 Mb.

Comment: Hi Petr, thanks for the answer. Do you have any reference for this?